# POCO HttpServer with nginx proxy

Tags: c++, proxy, nginx, poco-libraries

I recently came across with [POCO project](http://pocoproject.org) for c++ and pretty interested about it. It has also a builtin HttpServer that I want to play around.

I'm following the examples and built a simple http server listening on port 8000. Then I'm configuring my nginx to proxy_pass all requests to port 8000.

With proxy, browser shows content size as the very first character and adds 0 character to tail. For example I'm only responding with "test" string from HttpServer and then at the browser side the response is "4 test 0". When I directly access to port 8000 response is correctly shown without any numbers.

Because problem occurs when I use it with nginx proxy so I thought there is something wrong about my proxy settings. I read the [proxy configuration](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) wiki page of nginx but couldn't get any clue why this is happening.

my nginx conf as follows,

```
upstream pocotest {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://pocotest;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
                proxy_buffering on;

                proxy_pass_request_body on;
                proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting back is chunked encoded response. 4 is the length of the chunk with content "test". The 0 in the end of chunked message marker.
Most likley nginx is not adding Transfer-Encoding: chunked header to the response.